# What's the path of charged particle around a circular magnetic field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, integration

I'm trying to simulate electromagnetic fields. At the moment I'm exploring only magnetic fields (I know you can't have it without electric charge).

Anyway, I created a current carrying wire (just a line of moving particles) that generates a circular magnetic filed around it. I placed a particle near this wire with an initial velocity. Since I **turned off electric force**, just assume there's a circular magnetic field and I want to predict how will a particle move through this field.

[image]

[image: Particle revolving around circular magnetic field]

[image: Particle revolving around circular magnetic field]

Does this "superhelix" or "coiled coil" look plausible in this conditions? Since in a constant magnetic field, a moving particle will tend to move in circles, this might make sense since we are dealing with a circular magnetic field, but I would love to hear your thoughts on how accurate this is!

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field is $$\vec B =\frac{B}{r} e_\phi $$ in cylindrical $(r,\phi, z)$ coordinates. The path integral over $B$ along a circle of radius $r$ around the wire yields the current.

The vector potential can be assumed to be

$$\vec A = \text{const} + eB  \ \log( r) \ e_z$$

It follows that the Hamiltonian is

$$H = \frac{1}{2m}\ p_r^2 + \frac{L^2}{2m r^2} + \frac{1}{m}\left(p_3 -eB \log(r)\right)^2 $$

with $H, L,p_3$ conserved quantities, because the Hamiltonian is independent of $t, \phi, x_3$.

Notice that the constant canonical momentum $p_3 = m \dot z -eB \log(r)$ yields an ocillation of the kinetic momentum $m \dot z(t)$ with $\log(r(t))$

For small $r$, the effective potential in the r-Hamiltonian is a repulsive $L^2 / r^2$-potential with $L = m r(t) \dot \phi(t)$ the conserved angular momentum.

For larger r, the potential is attractive by $\log(r)^2$. The 3-component of the momentum is constant.

So we are left with a constant momentum, but oscillating velocity in the wire direction and an oscillation in the radial $r(t)$ direction.

The motion can  be inspected qualitatively by the effective potential and the fixed total energy level

```
  Plot[1/r^2 + Log[r]^2, {r, 0.01, 12}, 
             Epilog -> {Line[{{0.6, 4}, {7, 4}}]}]
```

[image: effective r-potential]

The very unharmonically varying radius $t\to r(t)$ is producing an unharmonically varying angular frequency by

$$m r(t) \dot \phi(t) = L $$ because
$(\log (r))^2 $ is a repulsive potential for $r\to 0$, too.

So, a winding helix seems consistent for large values of $L$.

It would be interesting to see what happens for small angular momentum values $L$, when the particle experiences a large $\phi$_tangential B-field at small r with large force in 3-direction.

Ah, yes, not to forget the cases of given angular momentum $L$, a small amount of energy just above the minimum of the effective potential, yields straight circular helices with an axis parallel to the wire, not enclosing the wire.